# AngularJS detect changes in DOM element's properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, event-loop

I've been struggling with this for the last two days, and got really confused from all the information and JS terminology out there.

The situation is as follows:
I have a form which elements are selectively visible, using bootstrap's tabs. I need to validate only the visible elements.

My approach:
Constantly getting all elements (form's children) that have `offsetWidth > 0` and `offsetHeight > 0` and storing them in a constantly changing array. When a form validation is needed **This is not true, see the edit!** *(e.g a submit button is clicked)* I just validate all elements in this array separately. Currently, I'm able to get all visible elements when the form is rendered, but when a new tab is clicked, the visible elements are different and I want to relpace the `visibleElements[]` array with the new content. What is the approach to look for `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties of an HTML DOM element and detect changes?

I hope my post is clear enough, but if you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:** There is no event fired for validating the form. The form is, let's say *live*, as the submit button has `ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` which is false if all fields are valid. I'm planning on replacing this with `ng-disabled="visibleFieldOne.$invalid || visibleFieldTwo.$invalid...."`.

Comment: Constantly getting elements in JS and doing stuff is anyway not good idea in Angular, why not u make ng-required, true/false for elements based on which tab is selected using a $scope variable. I am sure there is a way to get which tab is active in Controller.

Comment: Yes, I have a variable $scope.selectedTab, but I am not sure I get your idea, can you explain it a little deeper, please?

Comment: <input ng-required="selectedTab == 'thisTab'"/>

Comment: My God!!! Sometimes a lot of information can cause so much damage... Thank you so much, @suryapratap!!! You saved my day, my week, my month, and probably my job :)